# Python code get error in eclipse while it runs fine in terminal

Tags: python, eclipse, scipy, scikit-learn

I tried to run [sklearn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_roc.html), when I try to run it via terminal everything works fine but when I copy and paste this code in eclipse and try to run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/ABC/Documents/Eclipse/workspace/project/src/sklearn/plot_ROC.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sklearn import svm, datasets ImportError: cannot import name svm
```

I check that both eclipse and system using the same version of python (at least I think so)

In terminal when I typed "which python" the result is "//anaconda/bin/python"
And in eclipse I set the same for Python interpreter as you can see in below picture.
[image]

So can anyone guide me what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know eclipse very well but this kind of errors happens when PYTHONPATH is not set correctly. So you may have to check your environment section and be sure that PYTHONPATH contains the correct paths to your libraries.

Comment: @AndreaDiPersio I see your point, but as I mentioned in the question I tried to set the same path for both system and eclipse, the question is that am I do it right or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may compare Python path under Eclipse and terminal by

```
import sys
print ( sys.path )
```

the order of entries does matter. My guess is that the fact that your Python file is in a folder called `sklearn` ( i.e `.../project/src/sklearn`) is messing the import statement.

**requested edit**: as it turned out, the problem was that the Python script was in a folder called `sklearn` and Python would look into that folder to import `svm`.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA can you try renaming the folder to sth but not `sklearn` and see if it works?

Comment: WOW wonderful it works :) now I see what was my problem, how silly I am, can you write it as an answer so I can accept it.